# What zones can I grow Chinese Artichokes aka Crosne in?

Tags: hardiness-zone

I heard about Crosne from growing your greens, and thought I would try growing some, so I was wondering where/how I should grow them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crosne is hardy in zones 4 (−34.4 °C, −30 °F) - 8 (−12.2 °C, 10 °F).

It will grow in a variety of soil conditions, including sandy, loamy or even heavy clay. A pH of 6.5 to 7.5 is recommended. The most important consideration is that the soil needs to be quite moist, but well-draining, so the tuber (root system) isn't sitting in stagnant water. It will grow in the sun, but prefers some shade in warmer climates, especially in the afternoon.

If starting from scratch, use tubers that are firm, and haven't yet sprouted. Plant them about two to three inches deep, and at least a foot apart. As the plant grows, it will look like mint, as that's the family to which it belongs. Keep the plant clipped to about six inches all year round, and don't let it go to flower.

It can take many months until it's ready to harvest, so it's easier if you have a plant that's already growing.

Much of this information was sourced from [Vegetable Garden Planner](http://www.vegetablegardenplanner.com/vegetable_guides/crosne/garden_guide), and [Plants for a Future](http://www.pfaf.org/user/plant.aspx?LatinName=Stachys+affinis).